# HANA SQLScript "Sleep" Command

Tags: sql, hana

Is there an equivalent of a `Sleep(1000)` command in HANA SQLScript?

I'm not seeing anything in the HANA SQLScript reference, so I'm wondering if there might be a creative workaround that won't peg the CPU at 100%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HANA does not support anything like this out of the box.
There are two approaches that I can think of, if you absolutely HAVE to have this

### Busy Waiting

As already suggested on the [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3402302), you could create a procedure that is stuck in a while loop until a certain time threshold is reached. Mr. Amid Das suggested something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PLEASE_SLEEP ( IN SLEEPING_TIME INTEGER, OUT WOKE_UP_AT TIME )
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT READS SQL DATA AS
  V_TIME TIME;
  V_TIME_TO_WAKE TIME;
BEGIN
  V_TIME := CURRENT_TIME;
  V_TIME_TO_WAKE < ADD_SECONDS ( TO_TIME( V_TIME ), SLEEPING_TIME );
  WHILE V_TIME != V_TIME_TO_WAKE DO
    V_TIME := CURRENT_TIME ;
  END WHILE;
  WOKE_UP_AT := V_TIME_TO_WAKE ;
END
```

I am not sure how heavy the CPU usage will be, but it is definitely not the best.

### Using Table Lock Timeouts

This idea is a little bit crazy and complicated but might just work, without sacrificing too much CPU power.

The only SQL command that can "wait" is `LOCK TABLE`. This command will time out after a certain amount of time if a table lock could not be acquired. This timeout can be set using the `SET TRANSACTION LOCK WAIT TIMEOUT [number of milliseconds]`.

Now we just need a table that can be locked by the procedure, but also a **different** transaction that is keeping that table locked. This is the tricky part. What might work is using the XS Engine to schedule a continuous XS Job that will keep said table locked for as long as possible. Alternatively, you could write a Python script that will keep the table locked.

This idea is very experimental and I havent tried it myself. But I believe that it should work if everything is set up correctly.

Comment: When you're already using the XS engine then there's no need to abuse the LOCK TABLE command.

Comment: Lars, can you expand on that thought? Are you suggesting there might be another way to achieve a wait on the XS engine? I think the concern both Timo and I have is the execution _context_. If I'm executing a stored procedure outside of the XS engine, I don't have the ability to leverage the XS engine + a sleep() function call.

Comment: Well if you implement your code in the XS engine you could use JavaScript functionality like setTimeout to achieve a "sleep".

Comment: That's what I figure Lars was getting at. In my case, I'm trying to get around a clunky loop/sleep process in SAP Data Services and would rather create a procedure that simply waits until my asynchronous operation is complete.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use procedure SLEEP_SECONDS from library SYNCLIB.
I am using SAP HANA Platform 2.0 SPS 02 and its working.

Example of use:

```
BEGIN:
    USING SQLSCRIPT_SYNC AS SYNCLIB;
    CALL SYNCLIB:SLEEP_SECONDS(<TIME_IN_SECONDS>); 
END;
```

Documentation:
[HANA SQL Script Reference](https://help.sap.com/doc/6254b3bb439c4f409a979dc407b49c9b/2.0.02/en-us/sap_hana_sql_script_reference_en.pdf)